# Undefined function when changing synchronise ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am converting a function that used to load a synchronous ajax request to getDesign.php.  getDesign.php requests some images which are then displayed on the screen using the loadImages function.

Prior to the change I had:

```
      $d.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getDesign.php",
            data: {design : 1234,
                   type: ""
                    },      
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {               
             }
      });

loadImages() { // loads images }
```

I have now tried to change this as I understand the async part is now deprecated. The logic should still be the same - ie call the ajax function and then once it has returned something, call the loadImages function.  I can't figure out why the function "getDesign" is coming up as undefined when I load the script. Please can somebody take a look and see what I am doing wrong?

```
var $d = jQuery.noConflict();

function loadImages()
{
 // loads images
}

 $d(document).ready(function() {

      var getDesign = function() {  
          $d.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "getDesign.php",
                data: {design : 1234,
                       type: ""
                        },      
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {               
                 }
          });
      };      

      getDesign().done(loadImages());
  });
```

Many Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your **getDesign** does not return a promise, better it returns undefined.  It's enough to add a return:

```js
var $d = jQuery.noConflict();

function loadImages()
{
    // loads images
}

$d(document).ready(function() {

    var getDesign = function() {
        return $d.ajax({   // <-----  RETURN   HERE
            type: "POST",
            url: "getDesign.php",
            data: {design : 1234,
                type: ""
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
            }
        });
    };

    getDesign().done(loadImages);
});
```

Another mistake is in this line:

```
getDesign().done(loadImages());
                           ^^
```

change it to:

```
getDesign().done(loadImages);
```

The [.done()](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) requires a **doneCallbacks** not the result of the execution of your function.

Comment: Thanks for that. Do you know why the loadImages function isn't being called? I thought the logic would be the getDesign function would be marked as "done" once success has been reached. However, doesn't look like this happens?

Comment: @jagku Snippet updated: loadImages instead of loadImages()..... My bad.

Comment: Thanks!  I take it loadImages cannot have any parameters?

Comment: The parameters are the one returned by promise, .done().  See documentation for more help.

Comment: Thank you - will look online.